# XStream, сериализовать Null поля в пустые теги

Tags: java

Есть простой пример генерации XML с помощью XStream 1.4.11

```
@XStreamAlias("test")
class Test {
    public String firstName;
    public String secondName;
    public String lastName;

    public Test(String fname, String sname, String lname) { firstName = fname; secondName = sname; lastName = lname; }

    //.. getters and setters 
}
```

Может кто-то знает, как заставить при наличии Null поля генерировать пустой XML узел, а не просто выбрасывать его?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    XStream stream  = new XStream();
    stream.allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
    stream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

    String xml = stream.toXML(new Test("Ivan", "Ivanov", null));

    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

Вывод который есть:

```
<test>
    <firstName>Ivan</firstName>
    <secondName>Ivanov</secondName>
</test>
```

Вывод, который бы хотелось получить:

```
<test>
    <firstName>Ivan</firstName>
    <secondName>Ivanov</secondName>
    <lastName></lastName>
</test>
```

P.S. Если захотите предложить что-то лучше, то одна из проблем, что всё это дело должно работать на J2SE 5.0.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `registerConverter`/`registerLocalConverter`

Comment: тут есть пример с конвертером https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066360/xstream-serialize-null-values

Comment: @БогданСоловьев там ссылка битая, а в ответе только какая-то часть.

Answer (score 0):

Кривовато, немного сбивается порядок полей, но вроде как работает корректно с разнообразными типами полей.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    XStream stream  = new XStream();
    stream.allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
    stream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    stream.registerConverter(
        new TestConverter(stream.getMapper(), stream.getReflectionProvider()), 
        XStream.PRIORITY_VERY_LOW);    
    String xml = stream.toXML(new Test("Ivan", "Ivanov", null));

    System.out.println(xml);

    //Вычищаем пустые теги перед дессериализацией
    String newOne = xml.replaceAll("\\s*<(\\w+)><\\/(\\w+)>", "");
    Testform = (Test) stream.fromXML(newOne);
}
```

Код самого конвертера

```
public class TestConverter extends ReflectionConverter {

    public TestConverter(Mapper mapper, ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider) {
        super(mapper, reflectionProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doMarshal(Object source, 
                             HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, 
                             MarshallingContext context) {
        Field[] fields = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            try{ 
                if(field.get(source) == null) {
                    writer.startNode(field.getName());
                    writer.setValue("");
                    writer.endNode();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { /*логирование*/ };

        }
        super.doMarshal(source, writer, context);
    }
}
```